# prevent only horizontal scrolling on touch

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, touch

i basically created a very simple slider with `overflow:hidden` for the container so that i don't see the horizontal scrollbar and the only way i can slide to the next screen is clicking on a handle (a `span` in this case).

this works fine on desktop but on devices, you can still scroll horizontally touch swiping on the screen, is there a way to prevent this?

here's a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/5T3cV/

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it to be sure, but try setting the width of the html and body to 100%. Like so:

```
html, body{
    width:100%;
}
```